# Getting a 500 internal server error when using Jquery ajax post method

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

Help! I'm getting a 500 internal server error when using the jquery ajax post method in our production environment. I've had this problem before and never was able to figure it out. At the time, I just decided to change the "POST" method to "GET"...and that worked. But now it's more critical that I'm able to use the jquery ajax post method. It's just a simple ajax post call but for some reason it blows up internally in the production environment.

It's a web farm using windows 2008 server with IIS7.

This is all I'm doing.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    success: success,
    dataType: dataType
 });
```

Comment: You need to debug the server code or at least post the server log with error message here.

Comment: You'll have to have a look at the server logs - error 500 means there's something going wrong on the server side, so that's the best place to start. We are definitely not going to be able to debug this from the code you've provided.

Comment: Request is correct, your problem is server side. Check the server answer using soft like http://fiddler2.com/, it could help to understand this kind of problem. For example, it could be an undeclared variable used in PHP.

Comment: The server side has to support POST requests on the URL you are requesting. When the server gives an error it probably doesn't.So it may be helpful to ask a question with details to the server.

Comment: You should give some basic information about your server environment: PHP? Apache? IIS? ASP.NET MVC? What is it?

Comment: I updated the post per your comment...It's a web farm using windows 2008 server with IIS7.

Comment: Your update is not helpful

Comment: Check the post here http://www.developersnote.com/2014/01/solved-jquery-ajax-500-internal-server.html[link]

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Pretty much useless unless you're on LAMP .. sorry bud

Usually apache stores the logs in /var/log/apache2/error_log.1 for the current day (could be missing the .1 just do a ls -l | head )

This is assuming you're on LAMP.

For SSL errors add ssl_

Comment: As helpful as this may be for the OP, it's a comment not an answer to his problem.

Comment: No problem, I have thick skin. I updated my post. It's a web farm using windows 2008 server with IIS7. I didn't mention the event logs because they are pretty locked down, and there's a lot of red tape just to get to them. I was hoping someone might have already ran into this problem and figured out the solution.

Comment: 500 is the digital equivalent of a check engine light.. hard to really know unless you're there or you have a diagnostic tool.

Answer (score 1):

Is it just one piece of code you are having trouble with or "all" POST methods? Can you try the "test" template code below to verify if POST is working for even very basic server side methods. Your error is server side, so this is to verify that something will work server side at all. If this very basic code does not work, it can narrow down if it is your server side method that is the issue, or possibly the server configuration. I use code like this to verify I can POST at all before adding more complex methods. Also, use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) to really see what is going on as it can give you much more detail about the error.

Wherever your server side code is:

```
[WebMethod]
public string TestMethod(string test)
{
    return "I received the argument: " + test;
}
```

Your client side, using a newer version of JQuery:

```
<script>
$(function() {  
    var testVal = "this is a test string";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: "{'test':'" + testVal + "'}",
        url: "code.asmx/TestMethod",
        beforeSend: function() {}
    }).done(function(data) {

        alert(data.d);

    }).always(function() {

    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('Error: ' + errorThrown);
    })
});
</script>
```

And possibly needed in your web.config

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
    <webServices>
        <protocols>
            <add name="HttpPost"/>
        </protocols>
    </webServices>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling a web method of server side, verify that the name of the argument is the same as the data declaration.

for ex:

```
[WebMethod()]
public static bool MyMethod(string myData)
{... }
```

client side:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: "{'myData':'" + testVal + "'}",
    url: "code.asmx/TestMethod",
    beforeSend: function() {}
}).
```